# material ui button custom elevation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**How can I specify a custom elevation for a MUI Button?**

In MUI [Button API documentation](https://mui.com/api/button/) a `disableElevation` is documented (which seems to works as an alias of `elevation={0}`) but I can't find how I can specify an elevation different from the default one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep in mind that contained buttons use different elevation when hovered and when active/focused, so you need to take that into account when you customise them.

`@mui/system` has a [convenient way](https://mui.com/system/shadows) of applying shadows on elements without the `elevation` prop, using the `sx` prop. The syntax is `sx={{ boxShadow: 3 }}`, which is the same as `elevation={3}`. The numbers go from 0 to 24.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-button-custom-elevation-mdhgd)

Comment: Just note that elevation on the paper component for example, doesn't just affect the box shadow - it also applies a layer of lightening.

Comment: what should be done in that case? @dwjohnston

Comment: @RHOOPH As far as I know, only paper elements *are supposed to* get the lightening from elevation in dark mode. I could be wrong tho.